# 'identifier' : redefinition errors ( error C2011 & error C2370)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Every time I try to compile my code, I get a huge amount of errors. It's not a problem with my code, cause it was working just fine on another computer. I tried re-installing and fixing, but that didn't help. Here's the whole error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Raptor Triangle 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Raptor Triangle 2.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(57): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::YesNoMaybe' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(57) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::YesNoMaybe'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(67): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::AccessType' : 'enum' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(67) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::AccessType'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(81): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::Pre' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(81) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::Pre'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(78): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(112): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::Post' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(112) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::Post'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(109): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(143): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::FormatString' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(143) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::FormatString'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(155): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::InvalidCheck' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(155) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::InvalidCheck'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(152): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(165): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::Success' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(165) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::Success'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(176): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::PreBound' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(176) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::PreBound'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(173): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(186): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::PostBound' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(186) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::PostBound'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(183): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(196): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::PreRange' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(196) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::PreRange'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(193): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(208): error C2011: 'vc_attributes::PostRange' : 'struct' type redefinition
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(208) : see declaration of 'vc_attributes::PostRange'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(205): error C3094: 'repeatable': anonymous usage not allowed
1>          e:\programs\c++\raptor triangle 2\raptor triangle 2\predefined c++ attributes (compiler internal)(147) : see declaration of 'repeatable'
1>          attribute can only be applied to: 'class', 'struct'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(245): error C2370: 'SA_Yes' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(245) : see declaration of 'SA_Yes'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(246): error C2370: 'SA_No' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(246) : see declaration of 'SA_No'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(247): error C2370: 'SA_Maybe' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(247) : see declaration of 'SA_Maybe'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(250): error C2370: 'SA_NoAccess' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(250) : see declaration of 'SA_NoAccess'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(251): error C2370: 'SA_Read' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(251) : see declaration of 'SA_Read'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(252): error C2370: 'SA_Write' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(252) : see declaration of 'SA_Write'
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(253): error C2370: 'SA_ReadWrite' : redefinition; different storage class
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h(253) : see declaration of 'SA_ReadWrite'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Help? Haha. I don't get it. I looked up the error codes but couldn't figure out what to do.

Also, I can post the code if need be, but it's pretty long.

EDIT: I solved it, but I don't get why. I got rid of my line to include windows.h, which I needed for Sleep(). I still don't get why that matters though.

Comment: Are you including the same header twice?

Comment: You somehow broke #pragma once.  Hard to guess how that happened.  Notable is that YesNoMaybe appears at line 56, not 57.  Check the date on the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object files must be out of date. Try a clean build - i.e. Clean/Build. `windows.h` should have nothing to do with it.

Comment: But I commented windows.h out and it works now. So it has something to do with it

Comment: Not necessarily. Could be because you rebuilt. Just as an experiment, can you put it back and try a clean build? Please? :)

Comment: Well thanks. That worked. I'm new to C++, so I'm still learning. Thanks again

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, please explain what is underlying problem? Why rebuild solved the problem?

Comment: @Ruben I honestly don't know. Could be some stale headers that got dragged into an obj file, could be a precomiled header issue... beats me. If you really want to know, you can take it to MSDN forums.

Answer (score 5):

Another cause of C2370 is when multiple copies of a header file, containing a constant, exist.

Different projects then access different copies of the same header file, breaking the '#pragma once' and causing 'C2370 redefinition; different storage class'.

A common reason for file duplication to exist is when developers make a local copy of dependent library headers while a globally accessible still SDK exists.

Answer (score 4):

You need to form your header file as following:

```
#ifndef HEADERFILENAME_DEF
#define HEADERFILENAME_DEF

/* all declarations here */

#endif
```

This will prevent double inclusion of a header file.

Comment: But sourceannotations.h is built-in. Why would it suddenly not work? I didn't write it or edit it.

Comment: May be it doesn't contain such items and is include more than one time. Try to add.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VS2008. I resolved with:

```
change Yes (/Wp64) --> No
```